# C# WPF Limit items per row in a Listview

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

My Listview:

```
<ListView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GridViewItemTemplate}" Name="gridView_movies">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

Datatemplate of the list:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="GridViewItemTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
        <Image Width="250" Height="290" Source="{Binding Image}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

When i load this, all items are showed in one row, my question is, How can i show only 3 items per row instead of all items in one row.

Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use

```
<UniformGrid Columns="3" .../>
```

instead of `<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" .../>` in `ItemsPanelTemplate`

Comment: You also need to set the vertical alignment to Top, otherwise it will use all the available space and stretch the items to fill that space. Still, good idea ;)

Comment: +1, you had already answered while I was typing in my answer :)

Comment: Simple and keeps away from nested grids

Answer (score 1):

Use a `WrapPanel` instead of a `StackPanel`. It doesn't allow you to directly specify the number of items per row, but you can set the width of each item, which is almost as good. When there is no space left on a row, it continues on the next row.

EDIT: you could also use a `UniformGrid`, as suggested by Bonial. The drawback is that if you can resize your UI and make the `ListView` wider, the number of items per row won't change, and they will be stretched to fill the space. Depending on what you want, it might be OK, but I think `WrapPanel` is a better option in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

You want to replace that ListView.ItemsPanel StackPanel with a [WrapPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.wrappanel.aspx).  It will get the job done.  Once the WrapPanel has a width, it will then line wrap the items.